# Yii 1.1: Moment::toTimeZone() does not set the timezone

Tags: php, mysql, yii, timezone

Our application is built with Yii 1.1, and we have our `ActiveRecord.php` file setting up the timezone in a `formatTimeForAPICopy` method:

```
public static function formatTimeForAPICopy($timeString)
{
¦ if ($timeString) {
¦ ¦ $phDateTime = Moment::toTimeZone($timeString, 'Asia/Manila');
¦ ¦ return strtotime($phDateTime->format(MySQL::DATETIME_FORMAT));
¦ } else {
¦ ¦ return null;
¦ }
}
```

By using `\Yii::log` function, I can clearly see it's wrong. The time has -8 hours difference even using `date`. Also, the same happens to my local machine, which is even weirder.

I've checked MySQL's timezone configuration by using `SELECT @@global.time_zone`, and both local and server show `SYSTEM`.

I've tried using `DateTime` but it simply hangs the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define the timezone on config file (main.php) ? You can do it adding
...
'timeZone' => 'your time zone here',
...